# Phpstorm постоянно индексирует

Tags: phpstorm

Частично скачал проект с фтп и шторм постоянно индексирует около 10 файлов. Причем индексация вообще не останавливается: только показало, что завершено и все заново. Началось все с предыдущей версии 2017.2, обновился и на какое-то время эта проблема исчезла, а сегодня опять. Помогает включение энергосберегающего режима, но это не выход. При создании проекта с 0 такое наблюдается только с WordPress'ом. Остальные cms/cmf индексируются 1 раз + по мере необходимости. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ну WordPress точно ни при чем. У меня масса проектов на WP, такого эффекта нет. Индексирует один раз.

Comment: У меня тоже было подобное, когда работал с Ларавел. Но с следующим обновлением перестало индексировать. Либо попробуйте `Правой клавишей на папке -> Mask directory as -> Excluded`

Comment: Мой Вам совет, переходите на Atom, бросайте эту IDE.

Comment: ненавижу Atom. Глючный, тормозной. Просто поделка на electron'e. Вы еще Visual Studio Code предложите. Как текстовые редакторы годятся, но не более.

Comment: @entithat но это же не выход

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать так:
<kbd>File</kbd>`>`<kbd>Invalidate Cache / Restart...</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Источник.](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000755010-PhpStorm-keeps-indexing-over-and-over-again)

Comment: Оно вроде и помогло, но на некоторое время. Потом опять по новой(((